# Height of images used within carousel is not relating to the div used to hold the carousel

Tags: css, carousel

```css
 .mainIDv
 {
 height:300px;
 width:400px;
 padding:5px; 
 margin: 8px auto 8px auto;
 }
 .ImgDisp{ 
     background-color:cyan;
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
 }
 .carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="mainIDv">
<div class="ImgDisp">
  <div id="carouselSection" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carouselSection" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselSection" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselSection" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">

                                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" >
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Tomorrow land </h3>
                                    <p>We had good friends here!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>HappyLand</h3>
                                    <p>Thank you!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to create a slide show using carousel of bootstrap 4. I used the carousel code section within a div block. But my problem is height of images used within the carousel is not matching with the height of the div holding it. I tired every solutions suggested here, but none works for me. 
here is my code.

```
<div class="ImgDisp"> 
                    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">

                                    <img src="Images/Img12.png" alt="Los Angeles" >
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Tomorrow land </h3>
                                    <p>We had good friends here!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="Images/Img4.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>HappyLand</h3>
                                    <p>Thank you!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

I want images with height and width 100% matching with the div ImgDisp.
I tired overriding the styles defined for components like carousel, carousel-inner, carousel-item. but only width is working for me. Even tried to change the image styles.

```
.carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

I don't know why, somebody suggest a solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please create a snippet for your issue? Your images' sizes could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

you are overriding your img height by 10% in this style

```css
.carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 10% !important;
}
```

change it to 100%.

Comment: bro that was a mistake when I copied the code snippet.  That 10% was used to check my code. I even tried with 100%. Still no straight road.

Comment: problem that i figured out is with your image size and little bit with approach. you want your images with 100% height for example if the height of your div is 400 and the height of your image is 600 then your image will expands out of your div.

Comment: if you want 100% height and 100% width of your image than make sure that the size of div is greater than or equal to image size so image can fit in that div otherwise you can simply set your image as  height:auto , width:auto

Comment: your main div height is 300 and width is 400 in this case your image height should not be greater than 300 and width should not be greater than 400.